# How can I create a gpresult file in a folder I just created in the same powershell script?

Tags: powershell

how can I create a gpresult file to the new created folders?
The command in line 3 obviously won't work the way I want it to work.

```
$folderName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") 
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "T:\Tools\Testergebnisse" -Name $FolderName
gpresult /z > T:\Tools\Testergebnisse\Ergebnis.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the value of $foldername in a variable to use it in the path and use out-file to get your result into a txt file

Try something like this

```
$folderName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") 
$Folder= New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "T:\Tools\Testergebnisse" -Name 
$FolderName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
gpresult /z | Out-File T:\Tools\Testergebnisse\$Folder\Ergebnis.txt
```